# How Can I generate sequence No in SQL Query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Id  Desc     Sequenceno
-----------------------------
84  TEST         1
84  TEST2        2
84  TEST3        3
85  IPhone       1
85  IPhone1      2
87  Nokia        1
88  Vivo         1
88  Vivo1        2
```

I have `Id` and `Desc` Column. How can I get `Sequenceno` Column like above?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What platform of DB are you using?

Comment: Thanx Gordon to edit my question

Comment: platform SQL Server

Answer (score 4):

Use the ANSI-standard `row_number()` function:

```
select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by [desc]) as seqnum
from t;
```

Comment: select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by id desc) as seqnum
from t

Comment: Thanks for hint Gordon

Comment: @Sagarpadhiyar . . . `desc` is the name of the column.  Very bad name because it conflicts with a keyword.  I fixed the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  Id, [Desc], 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY Id) AS Sequenceno
FROM #Temp;
```